# Regular language ..are these elements of the set?

Tags: compiler-construction

I have a doubt...

Given L = {w belongs to {a,b}* | has as many a as b}

Are these, elements of the set L ?

L={ ab,aaabbb,aaaaaabbbbbb......}

Actually my concern is that there's a comma between a and b...

So perhaps I' wrong.
Thank you

Joachim

Answer (score 0):

You're misreading the question. `L` is a set containing `ab`, `aaabbb`, and `aaaaaabbbbbb`, among other things.

Comment: Thank you..But I can't see the other things...If the question was different..like L={  belongs to {ab}* | has as many a as b} my reasoning was correct ..Am I right?